# Common UI controls to be used throught the application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create some controls to be used through the code so that I don't repeat the code everywhere.
I mean I need to create custom control and use it within the viewcontrollers

example :

- Uitextfield that show datepicker popup at touch inside
- uitextfield with search button

any idea how to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use such controls often in your application, you can make a helper class with class and instance methods which draw the control you need and return it whenever you call the method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomControls : NSObject
//declare your methods 


@end
```

Comment: So If I need to create uitexfield custom , I will create a method that returns it , right ?! But I have a form contains already uitextfield

Comment: You can create a `xib` file and call it in your code whenever you want. So you did it once and use it multiple times ;)

Answer (score 1):

> uitextfield with search button

This is a good example to start with. I would solve this kind of problem by repeatedly loading a nib file. Every time you do that, you get a new copy of what's in it.

Make a new interface file (.xib) containing a view. Make the view invisible (background color = clear color). Put your textfield and search button into it. Now every time you load the .xib file, what you get is a view (the view that was in the .xib) that no one can see, containing a textfield and search button that they *can* see.

When I say "load the .xib file" I'm talking about this sort of thing:

```
 NSArray* objs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil];
```

Now `objs[0]` is a copy of the single top-level UIView from the nib! Now you can stick that UIView into your interface using `addSubview:` or whatever.

Comment: and how to insert it in my new xib , I mean I have many uitexfields

Comment: in code, you will load the xib and insert that invisible view (containing the textfield-and-search-button) into your interface wherever it is needed.

Comment: ok I created a viewcontroller with all the code to do that , how can add it to another xib at design time , am sorry for naive question

Comment: With what I'm suggesting you wouldn't use a view controller and you wouldn't add it to a xib at design time. In your main xib you could put a placeholder view. But (as I keep saying) what you would do is load the xib *at runtime*, in *code*, and fetch out the view from it and put it into your interface *at runtime*, in *code* (perhaps putting it where the placeholder view is).

Comment: this what I reached so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870216/custom-view-as-subview-never-appear