# UI template view - common UI elements in all scenes on iOs application?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uistoryboard

I'm developing iOs application with common UI elements - header (with custom butons), background image and footer across all scenes. It is possible to design one template scene/view using storyboard with common elements and use it in all other scenes/ViewControllers as a base? In other scenes just add content into free place (images, tables, ...).

I was thinking about common custom UIViewController superclass with hard-coded elements, but it's easier to design UI with storyboard.

Application has to be compatible with iOs 5.0

Comment: Remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869462/common-ui-controls-to-be-used-throught-the-application

Answer (score 2):

Options include:

1. Use custom container view controller. Put your common controls on that controller, and then using view controller containment for your child views. For more information, see

   - [WWDC 2011 - 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) video
   - [Implementing Custom View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in the *UIViewController Class Reference*
   - [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *UIViewController Programming Guide*
2. Define a `UIViewController` subclass that programmatically creates the common graphical elements and then subclass all of your other view controllers from that subclass.
3. Use `UIAppearance` protocol to define common look at feel for your controls. See:

   - [WWDC 2011 - 114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=114)

Personally, I'd use `UIAppearance` in conjunction with one of the other two approaches. I'd lean towards custom container controllers, but you lose the ability to do simple modal and push segues (I define a custom segue type that does the segueing between children), so I can understand why you might rather use a shared `UIViewController` subclass.